# React Native: "justifyContent" property not respected when children components specify "aspectRatio"

Tags: react-native, stylesheet

I'm facing this flex layout problem when working with this react native project. And here is the scenario:

I have a row which contains few circles, their styles are defined like this:

```css
rowStyle:{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderColor:"red",
        borderWidth:1,
    },
    
circleStyle:{
        flex:1,
        margin:10,
    },
```

[image]

As you can see, the circle's radius is a bit too big and they went out the row. So I added "aspectRatio:1," to the cycleStyle and get a result like this:

```css
circleStyle:{
        flex:1,
        aspectRatio:1,
        margin:10,
    },
```

[image]

Now, the row is a bit too short. I have to constraint the row's width. I tried to add

"alignSelf:'stretch'"

or

"width:Dimensions.get('window').width"

to the rowStyle, they both give me a result like this:
[image]

Now, the "justifyContent" property on rowStyle is disregarded somehow.

The question is how I can keep the circles stay inside the row and center align them while maintaining a maximum row width? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `paddingVertical` to rowStyle instead of `aspectRatio` to circleStyle.
Please share your component code along with your styleSheet for others to get proper idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There are multiple rows, each row has a style of "flex:1", so the actual row height can vary on different device screen. Set a fix paddingVertical to rowStyle won't help.

Comment: About the component code, the row is just a generic View component and Circles are Image components.